# .Htaccess no me permite utilizar / en URL amigable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

En mi .htaccess tengo lo siguiente:

```
RewriteRule ^topic=([0-9]+)\+autor=([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)\+titulo=(.*)$ /post.php?topic=$1&autor=$2&titulo=$3 [L]
```

el cual me permite utilizar una url de este tipo:

```
http://localhost/topic=8+autor=JhonDoe+titulo=Este-post-es-solo-prueba
```

el problema es que yo quisiera reemplazar los **`=`** y los **`+`** del .htaccess por  **`/`**

Debería de quedar algo así, si no me equivoco:

```
RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)\/autor=([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)\/titulo=(.*)$ /post.php?topic=$1&autor=$2&titulo=$3 [L]
```

para que me permita utilizar una url así:

```
http://localhost/topic/8/autor/JhonDoe/titulo/Este-post-es-solo-prueba
```

pero por alguna razón me sale error. ¿Qué hago mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás en lo correcto. Sólo falto terminar de reemplazar todos los caracteres:

```python
RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)\/autor=([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)\/titulo=(.*)$ /post.php?topic=$1&autor=$2&titulo=$3 [L]
                           ^      ^                  ^       ^
```

- Fataba reemplazar 2 `=`
- Si bien `\/` es válido, lo marqué porque no hace falta (sólo es necesario escapar las barras en motores de regex que las usan como delimitadores)

Quedaría:

```python
RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)/autor/([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)/titulo/(.*)$ /post.php?topic=$1&autor=$2&titulo=$3 [L]
```